# How to automate filter selection in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Need to automate filter selection in Excel VBA and repeat the sorting with entering letters as rating for each data in A1.
And another question when filter data has 1 visible row need to put lettering A in 3 cells: H, I, J

I tried with chatgpt and it works but need to choose from filter mannualy what to sort and count:

```
Sub macro1()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet3")

' Define arrays of column letters and criteria
Dim columns As Variant
columns = Array("E", "F", "G") ' Add more columns if needed

**Dim criteria As Variant
criteria = Array("condi","milks", "meat", "drinks", "nonfood", "gola", "salman", "hub", "hb\line.", "(empty1)") ' Add more criteria if needed
**
' Loop through each column
For colIndex = LBound(columns) To UBound(columns)

' Loop through each criterion
For critIndex = LBound(criteria) To UBound(criteria)

' Apply filter for the current criterion in column A
ws.Rows("1:1").AutoFilter
ws.Range("$1:$2968").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=criteria(critIndex)

' Sort by the current column in descending order
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range(columns(colIndex) & "1:" & columns(colIndex) & "2968"), _
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ws.AutoFilter.Sort
.Header = xlYes
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With

' Apply lettering to visible rows in the corresponding column
ApplyLettering ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row), _
ws.Range(columns(colIndex) & "2"), 7 + Asc(columns(colIndex)) - Asc("E")

Next critIndex
Next colIndex

End Sub

Sub ApplyLettering(rng As Range, targetRange As Range, offsetCol As Integer)
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim letterCount As Integer
    Dim letter As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim visibleRow As Range
    
    rowCount = 0
    For Each visibleRow In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
    Next visibleRow

    If rowCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' No visible rows
    
    letterCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(rowCount / 3, 0)
    
    i = 0 ' Start from the first visible row
    For Each visibleRow In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        i = i + 1
        If i <= letterCount Then
            letter = "A"
        ElseIf i <= 2 * letterCount Then
            letter = "B"
        Else
            letter = "C"
        End If
        visibleRow.Offset(0, offsetCol).Value = letter
    Next visibleRow
Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

---

Edit*
Found solution with chatgpt:

```
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
criteria = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("A2:A" & Lastrow).Value)
```